# How do I get my Sitecore 8.2 install to work with MongoDB 3.6 now that v3.4 is going to be EOL?

Tags: upgrade, mongodb

MongoDB has [announced end of life (EOL) support for MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy) version 3.4 in January 2020. The Sitecore KB [MongoDB compatibility article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/633863) for Sitecore 8.2 only shows version 3.4 as compatible. How do I stay supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution for Sitecore 8.2

Sitecore has released an upgrade process for version 8.2.7 to support MongoDb 3.6.6. Details can be found on the KB article here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/244364

> The following upgrade process has been tested with MongoDb 3.6.6.
>
> **Prerequisite:**
>
> Customers using Sitecore XP versions earlier than 8.2.7 must upgrade
>   to Sitecore XP 8.2.7.
>
> **Update procedure:**
>
> 1. Download the following archive: [CSharpDriver-2.5.0.zip](https://kb.sitecore.net/Services/Tracking/TrackEvent?ev=qObCs%2BaHKHySUxxzsLaQTwdlckI94oPMOUQUhWOYZ1ftGM2S8TlqxgWkhROxLvabGeYVUNrzNRMM08wZdkM9JGWNN0x%2FLrUuwne%2FM3oobIc%2Bqu4AoBFYlPTsx30NLmANW1hm92gIjsxCartCCAlMgj11YKMfcEG2wYuzhLi9U%2F1Afj85qA13HpNM1s7lvd1YJ6ggKBEDMAz5O1RzNnwpoc1mooX06xLwXr6ibp%2BX2J0%3D).
> 2. Extract the following assemblies from the \net45 folder inside the archive:
>
>    - MongoDB.Bson.dll
>    - MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
>    - MongoDB.Driver.dll
>    - MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll
> 3. Overwrite MongoDB driver assemblies in all
>      your Sitecore XP instances (located in the \bin folder) with the
>      assemblies mentioned in the previous step.

### Additional Options

More details and options are detailed on this blog: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/using-sitecore-8-2-with-mongo-3-4-time-for-an-upgrade

A summary of the options from that blog:

> **What are my options?**
>
> 1. **Upgrade to 8.2.7 and patch:** You can follow the instructions on our KB article to resolve the issue by first upgrading to 8.2.7 and then applying the patch to upgrade 8.2.7 to use MongoDB 3.6: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/244364
>
>    Please note that Sitecore 8.2 also reaches end of mainstream support on **December 31, 2019**. You will need to ensure you have purchased Extended Support for Sitecore 8.2 if you wish to continue having support on Sitecore version 8.2.
> 2. **Upgrade to 9.2 and MongoDB 4.0.5:** If you would like to continue using MongoDB, you can upgrade to Sitecore 9.2 which is compatible with Mongo 4.0.5. This gives you all the benefits of the latest release of Sitecore along with the most up to date Mongo version support. This also ensures you maintain active mainstream support.
> 3. **Upgrade to 9.0.2 or 9.1 and MongoDB 3.6:** This is an option if there is a reason that the 9.2 upgrade is not possible.There are some limitations on the MongoDB support in 9.0 and 9.1, which can be viewed on the MongoDB compatibility table.
> 4. **Upgrade to 9.x and SQL Server:** Starting with Sitecore 9.0, you can now use SQL Server instead of MongoDB. This is an option if you would prefer not having to manage MongoDB infrastructure going forward.
> 5. **Continue using current Sitecore version and MongoDB:** In this scenario,you will lose support for MongoDB from MongoDB support team as of January 2020.
>
>    Please note that Sitecore 8.2 also reaches end of mainstream support on **December 31, 2019**. You will need to ensure you have purchased Extended Support for Sitecore 8.2 if you wish to continue having support on Sitecore version 8.2.

Comment: Do you know how this impacts Sitecore Managed Cloud for xDB?

Comment: Hey Michael, that does sound like a different question (though related). I'll follow up internally. Sounds like a good addition to the blog, and a new SSE question to answer!